# Performance tuning with CONNECT BY LEVEL in query

Tags: sql, plsql, hierarchical-data

I have a table called `RULE_TABLE` which has columns  `RULE_SEG1` and `RULE_SEG2`

```
RULE_SEG1  | RULE_SEG2
-----------------------
????       | 0100?
0200       | 02*
484?       | ????
```

`COST_CENTRE_TABLE`

```
COST_CENTRE
----------- 
0000       
0100
0199
0200        
4841
4842
4842
```

`NATURAL_ACCOUNT_TABLE`

```
NATURAL_ACCOUNT
---------------
01001
01002
01005
01009
02001
02334
02611
12345
12347
12378
19999
```

Each rule in the `RULE_SEG1` and `RULE_SEG2` has to be expanded in the manner, if its `????` then it has to be expanded from 0000 till 9999; if its `484?`, then it has to be expanded from 4840 to 4849; if its `02*` then it has to be expanded from 02000 to 02999. The concatenated value generated from RULE_SEG1 and RULE_SEG2 is to be inserted in `MY_TABLE`. Also the values generated from `RULE_SEG1` and `RULE_SEG2`has to be compared with values in `COST_CENTRE` table and `NATURAL_ACCOUNT` table respectively only if the value returned by function `FV_SEGMENT_DESCRIPTION` is equal to 'COST_CENTRE' or 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT'. Functon `FN_SEGMENT_LENGTH` returns the lenth till which RULE_SEG1/ RULE_SEG2  has to be expanded.

Here's the code snippet that causes serious performance issues in Oracle 11g.

```
        for rec_rule in (select rule_seg1, rule_seg2 from rule_table)   loop                                               
    ln_seg1_len       number := fn_segment_length(rule_seg1);
    ln_seg2_len       number := fn_segment_length(rule_seg2);
    ln_seg1_len_power number := power(10, ln_seg1_len);
    ln_seg2_len_power number := power(10, ln_seg2_len);
    lv_seg_desc1      varchar2(100) := fv_segment_description(rule_seg1);
    lv_seg_desc2      varchar2(100) := fv_segment_description(rule_seg2);

    begin
    for rec_1 in (select b.num seg1
                   from (select a.num
                           from (select lpad(level - 1, ln_seg1_len, '0') as num
                                   from dual
                                 connect by level <= ln_seg1_len_power 
                                 ) a
                          where a.num like replace(rec_rule.rule_seg1, '?', '_')) b
                  where ((lv_seg_desc1 = 'COST_CENTRE' and exists
                         (select 1
                             from cost_centre_tbl c
                            where c.cost_centre = b.num
                              and rownum = 1)) or
                        (lv_seg_desc1 = 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT' and exists
                         (select 1
                             from natural_account_tbl n
                            where n.natural_account = b.num
                              and rownum = 1)) or
                        (lv_seg_desc1 <> 'COST_CENTRE' and
                        lv_seg_desc1 <> 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT'))) loop

     if lv_seg2 is not null then
       for rec_2 in (select b.num seg2
                       from (select a.num
                               from (select lpad(level - 1, ln_seg2_len, '0') as num
                                       from dual
                                     connect by level <= ln_seg2_len_power
                                     ) a
                              where a.num like
                                    replace(replace(rec_rule.rule_seg2, '?', '_'),
                                            '*',
                                            '%')) b
                      where ((lv_seg_desc2 = 'COST_CENTRE' and exists
                             (select 1
                                 from cost_centre_tbl c
                                where c.cost_centre = b.num
                                  and rownum = 1)) or
                            (lv_seg_desc2 = 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT' and exists
                             (select 1
                                 from natural_account_tbl n
                                where n.natural_account = b.num
                                  and rownum = 1)) or
                            (lv_seg_desc2 <> 'COST_CENTRE' and
                            lv_seg_desc3 <> 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT'))) loop

         lv_sourcekey := rec_1.seg1 || rec_2.seg2;

         ltab_map_level_2(l_cntr_level_2).sourcekey := lv_sourcekey;

         l_cntr_level_2 := l_cntr_level_2 + 1;

       end loop; -- rec_2
     end if;
    end loop;

    forall j in l_cntr_level_2 .first .. l_cntr_level_2 .last

    -- insert into staging table
     insert into my_table
     values
       (my_table_s.nextval,
        ltab_map_level_2                (j).sourcekey,
        );
    exception
    when others then
     dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end loop;
```

`RULE_TABLE` has 9800 rows, `COST_CENTRE_TABLE` had around 230 rows. `NATURAL_ACCOUNT_TABLE` has 936 rows. Total number of rows to be inserted into `MY_TABLE` is 220000. There is an index on `COST_CENTRE` in `COST_CENTRE_TABLE` and `NATURAL_ACCOUNT` in `NATURAL_ACCOUNT_TABLE`. The program takes 11.16 hours to run in development instance. Database is Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition. Please suggest ideas to tune the code. Explain Plan is not of much help except for the fact that the bottle neck is probably due to CONNECT BY LEVEL.

**AFTERTHOUGHT**
After analyzing the timestamp of data inserted into `MY_TABLE`, I found out that the maximum time taken is for the following two case:

**Case 1** when `RULE_SEG1` is `????` and it has to be expanded from 0000 to 9999
**Case 2** when `RULE_SEG2` is `*` and it has to be expanded from 00000 to 99999

```
    for rec_1 in (select b.num seg1
                   from (select a.num
                           from (select lpad(level - 1, ln_seg1_len, '0') as num
                                   from dual
                                 connect by level <= ln_seg1_len_power 
                                 ) a
                          where a.num like replace(rec_rule.rule_seg1, '?', '_')) b
                  where ((lv_seg_desc1 = 'COST_CENTRE' and exists
                         (select 1
                             from cost_centre_tbl c
                            where c.cost_centre = b.num
                              and rownum = 1)) or
                        (lv_seg_desc1 = 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT' and exists
                         (select 1
                             from natural_account_tbl n
                            where n.natural_account = b.num
                              and rownum = 1)) or
                        (lv_seg_desc1 <> 'COST_CENTRE' and
                        lv_seg_desc1 <> 'NATURAL_ACCOUNT')))
```

This loop expands the `RULE_SEG1` and checks if the resulting values exist in `COST_CENTRE_TABLE` (if lv_seg_desc1 = 'COST_CENTRE' ). Is there any way to design the `CONNECT BY LEVEL` query so that first it checks with the `COST_CENTRE` values and then expands. Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have enough information here to really make judgements about performance. 
We'd need explain plans and autotraces and such to really dig in. That said, here is my crazy suggestion:

Create an actual table with the values '0000' to '9999' and '00000' to '99999' to eliminate the 
`connect by level` part. If you think that's the limiting factor, get rid of it. Create a table 
ALL_ACCOUNTS with the expected results from your query. It's only 110000 records of 4-5 character strings. 
Absolutely TINY.

Then, simplify your logic. Your code is looking very procedural, which may be affecting performance. 
You could probably do most of this in one SQL. I don't have a database handy to fool around with, but this 
could serve as a guide:

```
insert into my_table( id, sourcekey )   
select 
    my_table_s.nextval,
    a.num seg1 || b.num seg2 as lv_sourcekey
from 
    (select num from ALL_ACCOUNTS where num like translate(rec_rule.rule_seg1, '?*', '_%')) a,
    (select num from ALL_ACCOUNTS where num like translate(rec_rule.rule_seg2, '?*', '_%')) b
where
    exists ( -- Conditions for seg1
        select 1
        from (
            select  'COST_CENTRE' as seg_desc,
                    cost_centre as acct
            from    cost_centre_tbl
            union
            select  'NATURAL_ACCOUNT' as seg_desc,
                    natural_account as acct
            from    natural_account_tbl ) comb1
        where lv_seg_desc1 = comb1.seg_desc and
            a.num = comb1.acct
    )
    AND exists ( -- Conditions for seg2
        select 1
        from (
            select  'COST_CENTRE' as seg_desc,
                    cost_centre as acct
            from    cost_centre_tbl
            union
            select  'NATURAL_ACCOUNT' as seg_desc,
                    natural_account as acct
            from    natural_account_tbl ) comb1
        where lv_seg_desc1 = comb1.seg_desc and
            a.num = comb1.acct
    )
;
```